# Power BI and autodesk Forge

Tags: powerbi, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-designautomation

Sorry if this question is off topic. I saw Forge example with power Bi.
Do I need Power Bi pro for Autodesk Forge development or free version would be sufficient?
So far understood , free version has 1 GB data handling capacity. Pro can handle 10 GB.
I guess free version is desktop version. Not completely sure, if free version is capable of cloud development. I searched online, but bit confusing.

Initially free version with 1gb data management capacity is enough for me, but is it capable of integrated in web app with forge app?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring to such  integration in this blog below (if not, please correct me)
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/embed-forge-viewer-inside-power-bi-report

This blog is about embedding Forge Viewer, a browser-based (using WebGL) component, to PowerBI report (in web app). Since it is browser based, it will load model to the cache of browser, so it does not matter with the storage size of subscription types of PowerBI.

While I do not investigate how it could work with desktop PowerBI. It is completely depending on how PowerBI supports WebGL in desktop. I saw one discussion which may help:
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/HeatMap-WebGL-not-supported-on-Device/td-p/414801

Comment: Thanks for the reply and bit of explanation and links.  I never used power BI. But in my new app I need to add it. I guess I need a 10 dollar subscription.